# listing available graphs in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am running into `ValueError: Tensor("conv2d_1/kernel:0", ...) must be from the same graph as Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", ...)`. I am trying to reuse a keras model with `Estimator` class.

I tried enclosing everything possible into

`g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():`

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    MODEL = get_keras_model(...)

    def model_fn(mode, features, labels, params):
        logits = MODEL(features)
        ...

    def parser(record):
        ...
    def get_dataset_inp_fn(filenames, epochs=20):
            def dataset_input_fn():
                dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
                dataset = dataset.map(parser)
                ...

with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    est = tf.estimator.Estimator(
            model_fn,
            model_dir=None,
            config=None,
            params={"optimizer": "AdamOptimizer",
                    "opt_params":{}}
            )
    est.train(get_dataset_inp_fn(["mydata.tfrecords"],epochs=20))
```

but that is not helpful.

Is there a way to list all graphs defined up to current point?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think you can mix Keras and estimators yet.. Looking at similar issues...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general debugging technique, put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into `tf.Graph` constructor, and then use `bt` to figure out who is creating the Graph. My first guess would that Keras does not use the default graph and creates its own. You can do `inspect.getsourcefile(tf.Graph)` to find where `Graph` file is located locally

Comment: it sounds circular, correct if wrong: I need to know where the constructor is in order to find out where the constructor is. What if I don't?

Comment: if you are using Conda, it would be in '~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py'

Answer (score 0):

The function that checks the graphs and returns the error (wish they return the graph addresses as well) calls following function to check the graphs:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import _get_graph_from_inputs
_get_graph_from_inputs([x])
```

In this case the graph that keras has created is identical to graph `g`, but one that is created by `get_dataset_inp_fn` is different from `g`.